# Como unir celdas con resultado de query?

Tags: php, sql-server, mssql

Tengo esta tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me gustaría algo así
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La primer tabla la genero de un resultado MSSQL así

```
<tbody>
                <?php
                    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
                            $idVenta = $row['idVenta'];
                            $fecha = $row['fecha']->format('d/m/Y');
                            $cliente = $row['cliente'];
                            $direccion = $row['direccion'];
                            $articulo = $row['articulo'];
                            $pendiente = $row['pendiente'];
                            $estado = $row['estado'];
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $idVenta; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fecha; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo "NOMBRE DEL CLIENTE"; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo "DIRECCION DEL CLIENTE"; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $articulo; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $pendiente; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $estado; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    }
                    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
                ?>
            </tbody>
```

Ya lo intenté con rowspan y nada, cuando hago eso la tabla se deforma por completo por las iteraciones del while, alguna sugerencia??

Comment: Si te sirven los artículos separados por comas y usas `MSSQL` en versión 2017 o superior, puedes usar la función `STRING-AGG` la cual convierte una serie de resultados en un único campo separado por comas. [Aquí la docu](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he conseguido haciendo un array de los articulos del resultado de la query e iterando solo los td y la ultima tr por cada articulo. No es el resultado que quería pero se ve mejor que el anterior.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$filas = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $idVenta = $row['idVenta'];
    $fecha = $row['fecha']->format('d/m/Y');
    $cliente = $row['cliente'];
    $direccion = $row['direccion'];
    $articulos[$row['articulo']] = [];
    $pendiente = number_format($row['pendiente'], 2, '.', '');
    $estado = $row['estado'];
}

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="<?php echo $filas; ?>" class="middle">
            <?php echo $idVenta; ?>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="<?php echo $filas; ?>" class="middle">
            <?php echo $fecha; ?>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="<?php echo $filas; ?>" class="middle">
            <?php echo $cliente; ?>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="<?php echo $filas; ?>" class="middle">
            <?php echo $direccion; ?>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="<?php echo $filas; ?>" class="middle">
            <?php echo $pendiente.' €'; ?>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="<?php echo $filas; ?>" class="middle">
            <?php echo $estado; ?>
        </td>
        <?php
            foreach ($articulos as $articulo => $value) {
        ?>
        <td>
            <?php echo $articulo; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
</tbody>
```